# IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX call never returns

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm writing a managed wrapper for the IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX function. It works fine on the flash drive that I've tested (using "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1" to get a handle). But when calling on \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 (the system drive), the function doesn't work properly, i.e.:

The first time it is called using the default buffer size, it returns the INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER error. When the buffer is automatically resized (using Marshal.GlobalHRealloc) and the function is called again, it never returns.

(I'm using a valid handle with no access permissions.)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the disk clean (no errors reported by Disk Management or `chkdsk`) ?  Does it work right in native code (e.g. C++)?

Comment: Also, your paths appear to be missing some `\\` backslashes

Comment: @BenVoigt - you're right. I didn't realize that S.O. was stripping them out without an escape character. The disk is fine. (It's my primary drive!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake.

When resizing the lpOutBuffer to accommodate the INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER error, I was using Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal without assigning the *returned* value to my lpOutBuffer. ReAllocHGlobal was releasing my pointer and giving me new one, which I had been ignoring, meaning that IOCTL was being called with an freed/invalid pointer. I don't know why Windows wasn't throwing an error, but I've solved my immediate issue.

(First I tried to enlarge the default buffer size, and it worked, that's how I realized that my follow-up calls must have a problem with the buffer/pointer, an viola! now everything works.)